# Random BSOD's on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, bsod

As of late I have been getting random BSOD's on a Windows 2012 R2 server.  It seems to be happening once a day, and can not pinpoint exactly why.  Any help with this would be amazing! I have done a registry clean, and also updated all drivers.  It seems to have started on the 28th of September out of random and I can't pinpoint anything that was done to the server that day or the day before to warrant this to be happening.  Here are the memory.dmp and the minidump.

ANY Help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vx50g65favxwn73/MEMORY.DMP?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmzf7d3srgi4dom/100415-40875-01.dmp?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the dumps?

Comment: Which error code(s) BSODs report?

Comment: Be very careful when sharing memory dumps with the internet, as they can contain sensitive data such as passwords, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE` in NETIO.SYS.

Stack trace:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
nt!KiFastFailDispatch+0xd0
nt!KiRaiseSecurityCheckFailure+0xf4
NDIS!ndisNsiEnumerateAllInterfaceInformation+0x25c0d <- This throws security exception
NETIO!NsiEnumerateObjectsAllParametersEx+0x20d
nsiproxy!NsippEnumerateObjectsAllParameters+0x201
nsiproxy!NsippDispatch+0x5a
nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x160
nt!IopXxxControlFile+0xd2d
nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
0x00007fff`9978124a
```

Looks like this bug: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dip/archive/2015/03/24/win2012r2-stop-0x139-or-0xd1-in-netio-nsienumerateobjectsallparametersex-0x20d.aspx

Try this hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3055343

They mention this bug happening every 24 hours, which perfectly matches your description. They also repro an identical stack trace. So I'm pretty confident that this hotfix has your name on it.

Comment: Amazing Ryan, Just installed, time to check to see if it fixes it in the next 24 hours!  Will let you know.